# Parent - Child Records and Ownership/data Skew

Tags: data-skew

I am aware of the concept of ownership skew (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/architect-salesforce-record-ownership-skew-for-peak-performance-in-large-data-volume-environments.html), but is this also a problem for a parent - child relationship outside the concept of owning a record?

A more specific example is I am looking at entitlements and currently every Case/Contact would be associated to the same entitlement. Would this cause any issues over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a slightly different problem, that article refers to ownership skew and you are referring to a data skew, which is what would happen when you have a large number of child records related to the same parent record, this issue happens more often around accounts but I guess it can happen in most master-child relationships.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/draes/draes.pdf

Comment: Thanks those links are helpful. So in theory as EntitlementId on EntitlementContact appears to be a master detail lookup to Entitlement we could hit performance issues at around 10K EntitlementContact records?

Comment: I think is technically possible but I wouldn't be concerned about those two particular objects because updating them doesn't have a big impact (or any?? ) on sharing across multiple other records, which is the case with other objects such as accounts or users.